# Unable to get Facebook permissions after HTTPMethod DELETE in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I am working on an app that logs in to Facebook using the FBSDK in Swift. I also have been able to make requests to get my wall posts by using

```
var request: FBSDKGraphRequest

request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/feed"), parameters: ["access_token": FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString], HTTPMethod:"GET")

request.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection, result, error) -> Void in

if error != nil
{

}
else
{

}

})
```

but I have been unable to get back results after I used the following to log out

```
var deletePermission = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/permissions/", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "DELETE")

deleterPermission.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection, result, error) -> Void in

if error != nil
{

}
else
{

}

})
```

When I log back in to the app, I am again asked to accept permissions, but when I check the expiration date for the current token with `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().expirationDate` I get a date before I tried HTTPMethod: DELETE.

So I was wondering how it would be possible to get back permission for your app or renew my access token because I don't think it's working by logging back in and accepting permissions. I have used the following to log out of the app

```
// Log out of the database I'm using
try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()

// Log out of Facebook, clear current token and logged user
FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)
FBSDKProfile.setCurrentProfile(nil)
```

I am also using `FBSDKLoginButton()' and setting the following permissions to log in

```
var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "user_friends", "user_about_me", "user_posts"]

loginButton.delegate = self

....

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

if error == nil
{

let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

// Firebase authentication
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) {(user, error) in 

if error == nil
{
    // No error found get user credentials through Firebase

}
else
{

}

}}
```

But again after logging in and going to another ViewController by segue and I check the current token to get "me/feed" I am not getting a reply and the token's expiration date has expired. Would it be easier to create a new app in Facebook developer and set it up in Xcode or is there something I can do to get my user posts?

Comment: I am using the new Firebase at [link](https://firebase.google.com)

Comment: Would be useful to me as well. What's the solution?